# Install gcsfuse in Google Cloud Container Optimized OS (COS)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

Does anyone know how do I install `gcsfuse` into a Google Container Optimized OS so that I could mount bucket in the VM instance itself.

I tried running a docker with gcsfuse mounted volume from host.  The docker container successfully mounted the bucket into the host volume.  When I view from the host volume, it is empty, but the container has the bucket data.

```
docker run --privileged -v /mnt/disks/bucket:/bucket \
  --device /dev/fuse \
  my_gcsfuse /go/bin/gcsfuse -o allow_other <BUCKET> /bucket
2020/12/16 23:27:21.161246 Initializing GCS connection.
2020/12/16 23:27:21.169616 File system has been successfully mounted.
```

From the container, I can see all files belong to gcs bucket files but not the host even I mounted the volume from host into the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue explained on this [git](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/profiles/apparmor/template.go#L35), the docker-default [apparmor](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/secure-apparmor#applying_a_custom_security_profile) profile denies all mounts. This '--security-opt apparmor=unconfined' [flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/apparmor/) make it possible to mount a GCS bucket.