# Install GCS FUSE in Google Cloud Container Optimized OS (COS)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse, google-container-optimized-os

Could you please provide the commands to install gcsfuse in Google Cloud Container Optimized OS (COS) and mount a bucket? Also I'm not sure which would be recommended, doing it directly on OS or on the container.

I came across this command [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65333210/install-gcsfuse-in-google-cloud-container-optimized-os-cos)

```
docker run --privileged -v /mnt/disks/bucket:/bucket --device /dev/fuse my_gcsfuse /go/bin/gcsfuse -o allow_other <BUCKET> /bucket
```

Is this the way to install and mount a bucket in Google Cloud Container Optimized OS (COS) at container level?

Comment: COS is designed to run container. Not sure you can do extra 'os' stuff before running the container.

Comment: COS is designed to be locked down. I do not recommend modifying the host OS with additional applications. For your use case, I use Compute Engine and configure the host as required. Then configure Docker to start the container(s) on system startup.

Answer (score 1):

Here 4 options that you may want to consider:

1. running docker from within a container (aka DIND) on COS is perfectly possible as you did, but read the answer for the link you posted, you must add a flag for the mount to work e2e
2. DIND is not really installing. If you really want to install, you can refer to a [hack](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/10463#issuecomment-1505509171) I used to install `docker-compose` and follow the installation [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcsfuse-install) for gcsfuse
3. you could use Cloud Run instead, and configure your `my_gcsfuse` (or use the latest official [Dockerfile](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/Dockerfile)) as a sidecar container. Sidecar and main  containers use shared volumes
4. if you use a custom image, merge both Dockerfiles - see the `builder` base image to copy the gcsfuse executable from - and use the new image to run on COS

The last option has my preference.

Answer (score 1):

GCSFuse currently does not support `Google Cloud Container Optimized OS (COS)`.

Please refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#supported-frameworks-os-architectures) to know more